# pygame screen automatically doubled

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I draw multiple patterns using Pygame and my screen width is 40 and height is also 40,but the problem is that when I run my code my screen size doubles automatically.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
size = [40, 40]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.get_window_size()
pygame.display.set_caption("Example code for the draw module")
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:
    clock.tick(10)    
    for event in pygame.event.get():  # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # If user clicked close
           done = True
    screen.fill((168,168,168))
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen,(192,192,192) , [30, 20, 15, 10], 2)
    fname = "shape1.png"
    pg.image.save(screen, fname)
    print("file {} has been saved".format(fname))
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()`
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have a high DPI monitor?

Answer (score 0):

you used an array (as indicated by square brackets []) instead of a tuple (parentheses ()). tuples are immutable, meaning they cannot be changed.

however, i didn't need to change this. the basis of your code seemed to work fine. it doesn't seem to change size for me. have you tested this on other computers as well? is this the entire code?
the only error that occurred was in the line `pygame.display.get_window_size()`.

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
size = (40, 40)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size) 
print(pygame.display.get_surface().get_size())
pygame.display.set_caption("Example code for the draw module")
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:
    clock.tick(10)    
    for event in pygame.event.get():  # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # If user clicked close
           done = True
    screen.fill((168,168,168))
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen,(192,192,192) , [30, 20, 15, 10], 2)
    fname = "shape1.png"
    pygame.image.save(screen, fname)
    print("file {} has been saved".format(fname))
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for contribution, there is no error my code runs actually but the problem is that the display screen of size 40x40 is look like as a rectangle shape  i think it should be square shape display screen.